# What is the correct plural form of a family name that ends in -i?

Tags: grammatical-number, names, surnames

I have just made a family group with my surname which is Karami, and I want to make my surname plural to show this is a family group, so I'm wondering whether I should add -s or -es?

Which one is correct?

1. The Karamis
2. The Karamies

A comparable group name would be the Cyruses.

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Or should the group name be just The Karami without an "s" at all?

Comment: You only use "ies" when the singular ends in "y", not when it ends in "i". That said, it's *your* group's name, and *your* family name, so *you* and you alone get to decide what's right. You can spell it any way you choose, and that will be the correct way.

Comment: And please note that naming things is expressly off-topic on this site. Thank you.

Comment: @RegDwigнt This question is about spelling, not naming.  The family already has a name, and the question is about how to spell the plural form of that name.  Spelling questions are expressly on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this post](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-make-family-names-plural), the OP recommend the first option.

> The Karamis